# The value from Accelerometer and Gravity sensor are not identocal

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, gravity

I understand the Accelerometer sensor is the hardware sensor and gravity is a kind of software sensor. But the values from them confused me a lot. I thought they should be identical when the device is rest on the table, but they are not. I try to put my phone on the table and the screen faces up...

Accelerometer: (-0.15, -0.15, 9.99) --> 9.99 m/s^2

Gravity: (-0.15, -0.14, 9.80) --> 9.80 m/s^2

The values from the accelerometer is strange, because the gravity should be 9.81 m/s^2 on the earth. What's wrong with the accelerometer? How can I solve this issue if I don't have the gravity sensor?

ps. I try many devices with the same result, so it should not be the hardware issue.

Comment: The difference is only about 2 %. I guess the sensor is just not that accurate. And btw. 9.81 is just an average, the real value varies a bit depending where you are on Earth.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. But I'd like to know how the gravity sensor make it close to real gravity values?

Comment: That's hard to tell without looking into the source code. According to documentation the two should give the same value when the device is not in motion. So again guessing here, it seems the gyroscope sensor that somehow influences the gravity value is also not that accurate and the two inaccuracies cancel by chance in your case.